# how to set position of scrollbar in windows form panel (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, scrollbar, panel

I have lots of `radiobutton` in a `panel` with auto scroll set to `true`. One of the `radiobutton` is checked. I want to make sure that that the checked one should be visible i.e. the vertical `scrollbar` should be moved so that the checked  `radiobutton` is visible.
Is there any way to do it?

P.S.  I have tried as bellow but it is not working

```cs
RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
.....
panel.Controls.Add(radioButton);
if (some logic)
{
    radioButton.Checked = true;
    panel.ScrollControlIntoView(radioButton);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but not working
panel.AutoScrollPosition = radioButton.Location

Comment: Also I am not able set value of panel.AutoScrollPosition, it is always 0,0

Comment: setting this.ActiveControl to the checked radio button helps though. But it will fix the problem if I have one such panel. Unfortunately I have two panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, I add the above mentioned code (`panel.ScrollControlIntoView(radioButton)`) after the form is shown (i.e. in the event handler for `form_Shown` event).

This is working now. But I still don't have the correct explanation for this.

Comment: it will be great if anybody could give explanation for this behavior. Thanks